# Bounded Subsets

Tags: real-analysis

I've been struggling with a question on bounded subsets for a few days now. The question is:

Let A,B be two non-empty bounded subsets of R. Show that the set 
$$C:=\{x\cdot y:x\in A, y\in B\}$$
is bounded.

I know what the definition of a bounded set is, I just can't see how to show this from the definition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the real numbers $\Bbb R$.  Because $A$ is bounded, you know that for some $M_1, |x| \lt M_1$.  Because $B$ is bounded, you know that for some $M_2, |y| \lt M_2$.  What does that tell you about $|xy|$?